# How do you handle unity freezes?

Tags: 11.04, unity, freeze

This is a question in general. Sometimes when using Natty, the interface freezes like the keyboard works but the mouse does respond. In which case pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 puts me at the terminal. However I do not know how to load the GUI and Unity and continue using Ubuntu. At present I just shutdown properly and restart.

I have no expertise in this regard, which is probably why some of the terms I use could be wrong. Please correct me if necessary.

**How do I restart the Xserver or GUI(Gnome and Unity) when I press Ctrl+Alt+F1?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  My personal favourite is to login to the F1 text console as yourself. Then type

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

This should kill you previous X server and restart it.  Sometimes it fails to kill properly, but it will start another X server on tty8 (CTRL + ALT + F8)

Answer (score 1):

You can restart X in 2 different ways staying at graphical tty (i.e. tty7).

- First you can try

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

(this shortcut isn't enabled by default. To enable, go to Menu > System > Preferences > Keyboard > Layout > Options > Key sequence to kill X server).

---

- If it doens't work you can use the kernel to do this. The "shortcut" is:

  <kbd>Sys Rq</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

  (or for laptops:

  <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Sys Rq</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>)

For reference, see Wikipedia: [Magic SysRq key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `ALT+F2` you can try `"unity --replace`" OR "`unity --reset-icons`"

Comment: No, unity --resets will remove all user configurations of unity. I think you meant unity --replace instead.

Comment: I think you mean `unity --replace` which starts a new program in place.